# Access-Control-Allow-Origin ISSUES

Tags: http, http-headers

SOme of my clients from the UK are not able to see a module of mine which use the Twitter api.
WHen ilogin remotely and check the errors , i get the following.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.getmytweets.co.uk/?screenname=philipbeel&limit=5&undefined=undefined. Origin http://plugins.theodin.co.uk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Accoring to another related question on stackoverflow i can resolve this by adding a HTTP response header to allow  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

HOW can i do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this. Infact a solution. The new twitter API 1.1 uses a Oauth plugin. So there is a PHP code which i got from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and entered the keys i got by registering an application on twitter and then i used the json generated by the php and formatted it using jquery using another javascript...

This is the solution i got from http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

Thanks a lot TOM